# Stackoverflow search results appear on top each other

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, google-chrome, search

In the last few days search queries results are stacked on top of each other making it impossible to search.

See screenshot.

[image: screeshot]

System: Chrome 21.0.1155.2 dev-m (Dev branch) on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Use a stable browser...

Comment: reset your zoom level. [Chrome dev track float glitch (21.0.1155.2 dev-m)](http://superuser.com/questions/430925/430946#430946)

Comment: @nic - I'll bet marking a bug as **[status-declined]** feels really good ;)

Comment: it's not the zoom issue, i'm on zoom 100%

Comment: @Lix - after a 2 week vacation, it's a good way to start back, yes :)

Comment: @Sathya: I've seen this on a few sites in 21.0.1155.2 dev-m and reset zoom level does fix it, but that doesn't appear to work on SO.

Comment: `.fl, .question-summary { float: none !important; }` will fix it in Chromium 21.0.1152.0. Add it to [custom.css](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12079789/1113772)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No repro here on Win7/64 in Chrome "20.0.1132.21 beta-m".

I think this is a problem with the dev build. We do not support pre-release browsers.

Feel free to report it **to them** as a bug though.

edit: I can't repro on "21.0.1163.0 canary" either

Comment: Yeah, I had seen this issue on Canary a few days ago. Gone now.

Comment: Thanks, if this doesn't go away in a few days I'll report to chromium.

Answer (score 5):

IMO, Stack Overflow doesn't have to  accommodate for developer branches or unstable versions of browsers...

By using an unstable/non-final version of a browser you are opening yourself up to the possibility that your browsing experience will not be perfect.

> Related - [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Answer (score 3):

Chrome dev is an unsupported browser.

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/178438):

> **"We support current and previous versions of all browsers with some reasonable amount of market share, but not beta or dev versions." –Jeff, paraphrased ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/56192#56192)); subsequently [reaffirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124101/search-box-maximisation-changes-cursor-position-unintuitively#comment331638_124101) by [other devs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125368/possible-problem-of-upvoting-in-stack-overflow-on-firefox-10-0-2#comment338155_125368)**

The bug is on Chrome's side, and SE probably won't do anything to fix it. Wait for a millisecond-update. Or switch to [Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs) and install beta/stable alongside it.