# CSS on search causes unreadable overlap

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stackoverflow search results appear on top each other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134452/stackoverflow-search-results-appear-on-top-each-other)

I'm experiencing the following CSS issue when using search (both on SO and meta):

[image: CSS Overlap Issue -- Google Chrome 21]

I've traced the issue to all.css (same thing happens on meta, with v=07b20e653b8a if that means anything to you).

Chrome inspector says:

```
.question-summary {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 11px 0px;
    width: 730px;
    float: left;
}
```

and if I delete `float: left`, everything is correct.  I suspect this either shouldn't be in the CSS or a clearfix is needed.

- Browser: Chrome 21.0.1156.0 canary
- OS: Mac 10.6.7