# Search results unusable when query includes tagged and untagged text

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, markdown, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stackoverflow search results appear on top each other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134452/stackoverflow-search-results-appear-on-top-each-other)

When I search using any tagged string along with an untagged string, I get this:

[image: search results for [data] foo]

Same issue occurs in safe/private mode with extensions disabled:

[image]

Other search criteria display results normally. I can fix the layout mysel if I remove `float:left` from the `question-summary` class in all.css or redefine it in a user style sheet.

Comment: no repro. . . .

Comment: Browser Tab Overflow

Answer (score 1):

You have a user script/extension of some sort that's changing styles and making all of the search results stack on top of one another...that's not from our end though.

Comment: I've updated the bug with more details.

Comment: @PaulSweatte it's still a client-side issue with an extension you're using, or a proxy you're getting content from...the page itself *definitely* doesn't render like that.

Comment: I'm not using any extensions or plugins except Flash. I am blocking cookies from pixel.quantserve.com. I noticed `tageditor.js` is included when it renders correctly, but not when it renders incorrectly. Oh well, thanks for your time.